# Last item in il to big

Tags: html-lists

Hello I'm trying to make a menu and make 2 rows of 4 buttons. My problem is that the list item in each row is taller then all the rest. I've tried searching to find an answer but I'm not exactly sure on how to word it to find the answer I'm looking for.

I've tried specifying the dimensions in the #menu li# a { part of the css for each one but it didn't visibly have an affect. Any input is appreciated.

My code is as follows.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>xxxxxxxx</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: black;
margin: 0;
}
#menu {
width: 850px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#menu2 {
width: 850px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#menu li {
float: left;
border: 2px solid yellow;
text-indent: -9999px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#menu2 li {
float: left;
border: 2px solid yellow;
text-indent: -9999px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#menu li a {
display: block;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
}
#menu2 li a {
display: block;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
}
#menu li#homepage a {
background: url(New_Homepage.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu2 li#newsletter a {
background: url(New_Newsletter.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu li#homepage a:hover {
background: url(New_Homepage_knife.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu2 li#newsletter a:hover {
background: url(New_Newsletter_knife.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu li#welcome a {
background: url(New_Welcome.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu2 li#phonebook a {
background: url(New_Phonebook.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu li#welcome a:hover {
background: url(New_Welcome_knife.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu2 li#phonebook a:hover {
background: url(New_Phonebook_knife.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu li#leadership a {
background: url(New_Leadership.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu2 li#ombudsman a {
background: url(New_Ombudsman.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu li#leadership a:hover {
background: url(New_Leadership_knife.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu2 li#ombudsman a:hover {
background: url(New_Ombudsman_knife.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu li#history a {
background: url(New_History.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu2 li#pao a {
background: url(New_PAO.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu li#history a:hover {
background: url(New_History_knife.JPG) no-repeat;
}
#menu2 li#pao a:hover {
background: url(New_PAO_knife.JPG) no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="POSTER.JPG" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="90%"></div>
<div>   
<ul id="menu">
<li id="homepage"><a href="homepage.htm">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
<li id="welcome"><a href="Welcome.htm">WELCOME</a></li>
<li id="leadership"><a href="leadership.htm">LEADERSHIP</a></li>
<li id="history"><a href="history.htm">HISTORY</a></li>
<br class=clear>
</ul>
<ul id="menu2">
<li id="newsletter"><a href="newsletter.htm">NEWSLETTER</a></li>
<li id="phonebook"><a href="phonebook.htm">PHONE BOOK</a></li>
<li id="ombudsman"><a href="ombudsman.htm">OMBUDSMAN</a></li>
<li id="pao"><a href="pao.htm">PAO</a></li>
<br class=clear>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

"list item in each row is taller then all the rest."

by looking at your css, your list item should be all the same height because you specify a height in your a tag inside your li tag

first of all you dont need two id #menu and #menu2, because they have the same properties
you should change it to class, also u dont need "`<Br />`" before `</ul>`

HTML :

```
    <ul class="menustyle" id="menu"> 
       <li id="homepage"><a href="homepage.htm">HOMEPAGE</a></li> 
       <li id="welcome"><a href="Welcome.htm">WELCOME</a></li> 
       <li id="leadership"><a href="leadership.htm">LEADERSHIP</a></li> 
       <li id="history"><a href="history.htm">HISTORY</a></li> 
    </ul> 
    <ul class="menustyle" id="menu2"> 
       <li id="newsletter"><a href="newsletter.htm">NEWSLETTER</a></li> 
       <li id="phonebook"><a href="phonebook.htm">PHONE BOOK</a></li> 
       <li id="ombudsman"><a href="ombudsman.htm">OMBUDSMAN</a></li> 
       <li id="pao"><a href="pao.htm">PAO</a></li> 
    </ul>
```

CSS :

```
 .menustyle {
      clear:both;
      width: 850px;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .menustyle li {
      float: left;
      border: 2px solid yellow;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 50px;
    }   
    .menustyle  li a {
      display: block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 50px;
    }

    /*for each id, i just make this for example*/
.menustyle li a{ background:url('http://www.braford.org.au/MidgeeBrafords/images/button_midgee_history_up.gif'); }
```

is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/EKycL/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
<br class=clear>
</ul>
```

You need to put that break outside of the list. Like this:

```
</ul>
<br class=clear>
```